# ARP spoofing + DNS spoofing

Tags: arp-spoofing, dns-spoofing

To make a prank on a friend, and also for educational purposes, I am trying to hack a DNS server in my local network. I am using Windows. I used [arpspoof](https://github.com/alandau/arpspoof/) from GitHub.

Can someone please elaborate on how to take the next step on altering the default DNS server on a router? Or is there any source code I can study which includes WinPcap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how such an attack works. You would not alter the default DNS server on the router after ARP spoofing. You could carry out an attack as following:

1. Become man-in-the-middle with ARP spoofing (this allows you to capture DNS request packets; also don't forward the captured DNS requests, so you don't have to race against the actual DNS server).
2. Write a program that answers to every captured DNS request packet with a DNS response packet containing an IP address of your choice. (e.g. www.google.com pointing to 10.0.0.24, which is your malicious service). For DNS spoofing on Windows you can use https://github.com/Trackbool/DerpNSpoof.

Also have a look at this: https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/how-i-pranked-my-friend-using-dns-spoofing-6a65ff01da1